# How to select where st_contains one or more points

Tags: sql, mariadb, spatial, spatial-query

How can I select all rows where a polygon column st_conatins one or more points,
I have a list of points and I want to select all rows where at least one of the points is in thiere polygon

For example, this query will give me all areas that contain a single point

```sql
SELECT *
FROM areas
WHERE ST_Contains(areas.geometry, POINT('lon', 'lat'))
```

But what I want is to test against multiple points (like IN query), hypothetical code would be

```sql
SELECT *
FROM areas
WHERE ST_Contains(areas.geometry, IN(POINT('lon', 'lat'), POINT('lon2', 'lat2'), POINT('lon3', 'lat3')))
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a table of points of interest and EXISTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking each single point use a collection of points with `MULTIPOINT'

```
SET @mp:= GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(1 1, 3 3, 9 9)');
SET @area:= GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0))');
```

Since `ST_CONTAINS` returns TRUE only if all points are in the area, you have to use `ST_INTERSECTS` instead.

```
select st_intersects(@mp,@area);
+--------------------------+
| st_intersects(@mp,@area) |
+--------------------------+
|                        1 |
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR with the WHERE clause.

This will allow multiple different conditions to satisfy the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM areas
WHERE ST_Contains(areas.geometry, POINT('lon', 'lat'))
OR ST_Contains(areas.geometry, POINT('lon2', 'lat2'))
OR ST_Contains(areas.geometry, POINT('lon3', 'lat3'))
```